# Do Manchurian Nationalists want Independence?

Tags: china, nationalism, qing-dynasty

Manchuria existed from the Middle Ages to present-day China.

> The Qing dynasty was founded by the Jurchen Aisin Gioro clan in Manchuria in the late 16th Century. *[Wikipedia:Qing Dynasty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty)*

The Qing dynasty ruled Manchuria and China, but ended in 1912 and succeeded into the Republic of China. Ever since then, Manchuria have had little power or authority over there Eastern China territory. Does this push them to get independence? Have they ever tried it before?

Comment: Much of this question seems to be asking about present day Manchurian nationalists, as implied by the present tense. Those parts should go in Politics.SE rather than History. Whether they tried it before is answerable as a historical question, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Have they ever tried it before?

Yes, after the foundation of the republic, Manchurian elites fostered Manchurian nationalism in the dreams of an imperial restoration. The existence of this movement was one of the factors that culminated in the creation of Manchukuo by Japan in 1932.

A prominent example is [Asin-Gioro Xi Qia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_Qia), a distant member of the Qing imperial house. He defected to the Japanese during their invasion of Manchuria, and became one of the collaborators who proposed the creation of a Manchurian state under the Last Qing Emperor, Pu Yi.

However, the Manchukuo state was ruled as a Japanese puppet. All ethnicities within its jurisdiction were given citizenship, not just ethnic Manchus. So in practice the nationalist dream of an independent Manchurian nation state was completely dashed, and evaporated along with the puppet state in 1945.

Answer (score 0):

Manchukuo was a puppet state.  By the time, the Manchurian rule came to an end in 1912, the Manchurian people had pretty much ceased to exist.

The Manchurian people and civilization had essentially been fully integrated into the Chinese civilization/culture through intermarriage and cultural assimilation.

Thus by the time Qing dynasty ended, there was pretty much no 'pure' Manchurian (people of manchurian blood, language and tradition) left to bring over to Manchukuo.

No one in modern china is pure anything..  China is actually the true melting pot.  there is a reason chinese didn't invent M&M or Skittles.